# Woocommerce - 2 free samples, then a user must pay

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m building a website for a client which will run on Woocommerce, and need to offer samples for each individual product. The products are floor tiles, and they'd like to offer samples of the tiles. However, to avoid a situation where users can order massive amounts of tiles for free, they'd like the functionality to be such that each user of the website can order 2 free samples, thereafter they have to pay (for example £5 per sample). With perhaps some other conditions as well, but the “2 free – then you have to pay” is the basic functionality required.

There are a couple of Woocommerce Samples plugins I've found, but none of them offer the paid functionality. Does this sound like something which is possible?

Comment: This would be very tricky to implement, plus you'd have the potential for people to just create new accounts to get more samples. I'd suggest that if you reallz had to implement free samples, that you issue people with a unique coupon that has a limited usage. I'd imagine there is already a WooCommerce extension that offers this sort of functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Phill. The issue of them creating new accounts to order another sample is probably not that bad - they're aware that people will always be able to get around it if they really want to, it's just to have the basic behaviour be that they get 2 samples free, then pay thereafter. Doesn't matter if they can get around it. Thank you for the coupon suggestion, i'll look into that now!

Comment: The implementation would still likely be best done as I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this would be to use the coupon code functionality of WooCommerce. You can give customers a code which limits them to 2 free tiles and then that code expires and cannot be used by them or anyone else ever again.

If you really do not care that some people will create new accounts in order to try and cheat their way to many free tiles you can just create a single coupon code that anyone can use but limit each user to only using the coupon code for two tiles. You can advertise it on your site "Use the coupon code 'FREESAMPLE' to get two free tiles" and post it on social media and in email campaigns to drive traffic.

You could probably code this in or find some sort of plugin that will do it as well but it the coupon code would be the quickest and most efficient way, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post was created quite some time ago, but Both Phil and Dan are making the free samples sound like a promotion which you would use for luring customers in. But regarding tiles, this is the wrong way to go about free samples. It is not a promotion, but instead it is a sample of the product before to ensure the correct match to what the customers are looking for.

However, now there is a plugin to support exactly what you require:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-free-product-sample/

***Free product samples for WooCommerce*** allows your users to order a free sample direct from the single product pages, set the amount of free samples allowed of each product, and the premium version allows you to edit the shipping rates of the sample as well (instead of using the standard rates you have applied for lets say 1 full box of tiles). The button text can be fully customised, and the look of the button takes on the appearance of your sites global button look and feel to match the rest of your site.

I believe this would be a better option to match your requirements than using coupons. I used this same method for a Fabric & Material store I created and it works perfectly! Which is a very similar scenario to your own.